# Git remove all but one file

Tags: git

After using read-tree for moving a file to another repository (while preserving history), I want to remove all other files in the folder that are indexed apart from the particular file.
How do I achieve that?

```
1.) git read-tree --prefix=folderName/ repB:folderName
2.) git rm --cached model/<all files except moved file which is say named test.txt>
```

What do I insert in <> above?

Comment: Have you tried `model/!test.txt`?

Comment: `git restore` after removing?